# Does MySQL have a built-in way to tell whether a view is insertable (not just updatable)? E.g., something like the IS_UPDATABLE flag, but for INSERT?

Tags: mysql, update, insert, view, information-schema

The MySQL documentation for [the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/8.0/en/information-schema-views-table.html) mentions that MySQL sets a flag whenever a view is created that records whether that view is *updatable*, i.e., whether you can UPDATE the rows of the underlying physical tables that make up the view by querying the view. Elsewhere, in the documentation for ["Updatable and Insertable Views"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html), it mentions that there are additional rules to determine whether a view is *insertable*, i.e. whether you can INSERT new rows into the actual physical tables underlying the view by querying the view. I understand these rules, and I know that I could manually go through each view's definition and record whether each view is insertable myself, but what I want to know is whether there's an easy way to just pull up whether a view is insertable or not, like we can with whether a view is updatable. It would make sense that an IS_INSERTABLE flag would be visible to the user, since the IS_UPDATABLE flag is made visible to the user and MySQL distinguishes between insertability and updatability, but I couldn't find any mention of an IS_INSERTABLE flag or anything like it anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: Add a feature request at bugs.mysql.com

Comment: So there is no built-in feature to determine whether a view is insertable, then? If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: Let's wait to see if someone comes up with the flag _or_ a way to deduce the value in some tricky way.